# Optional fields in CSV parser

Tags: java, univocity

I am writing code to read a CSV file.

```
A, B, C
1, 1, 1
2, 2, 2
```

Sometimes column C will be present, and sometimes it will not be. If it's not, I really don't care, but if it is I want to handle it. I'm also using the Univocity parsers, but don't necessarily have to.

```java
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
parser.beginParsing(file);

Record record;
parser.getRecordMetadata();

while ((record = parser.parseNextRecord()) != null) {
   String a = record.getString("A");
   long b = record.getLong("B");
   long c = record.getLong("C");
}
```

I can do something like

```java
long c = 1;
try{
  c = record.getLong("C");
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

But this seems needlessly complex. Is there some kind of setting that makes a field entirely optional?

Comment: As a note, this question is precisely the opposite of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56792683/843419)

Comment: Is your `Record` the same as [CSVRecord?](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVRecord.html) I want to make sure I understand what API is being used.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using the univocity parsers, `com.univocity.parsers.common.record.Record`. Will edit question.

Answer (score 1):

Record contains a `getValues()` method that returns all values.  You could use this to check the number of values to avoid an exception.

```
if( record.getValues().length > 2 )
  long c = record.getLong("C");
```

Untested, I just glanced at the API docs.

(The Apache CSV parser has a CSVRecord with a `size()` method you can test directly, with less (I assume) overhead.  In case you might be interested in switching.)

Comment: This is a good idea, but in my use case I can also imagine that there might be additional columns that I want to ignore. Thus there might be three columns, `[A, B, D]` and I want to just get the values of A and B

Comment: It would result in a cascade of `if` checks, sure.  You might be able to improve things with a method call to encapsulate some of the over head.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the isMapped method from CSVrecord

```
if(record.isMapped("C")){
 c = record.getLong("C");
} else ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, `Header name 'C' not found. Available columns are: [a, b]`

Comment: I see.
I wanted to change my anyswer anyways after I checked out CSVRecord.